# FLUTTER ERROR :"why am I getting Vertical viewport was given unbounded height while displaying data from fire cloud?"

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

here is the code

```
isClicked? StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: db.where("Uid", isEqualTo: Uid.text).snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListView(
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
              return ListView(
                children: [
                  Text(doc.data()['name']),
                  Text(doc.data()['DateOfBirth']),
                  Text(doc.data()['crime']),
                  Text(doc.data()['criminalHistory']),
                ],
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  )
:Container()
    ]));
```

}
i have tried to replace list view with column ,and inner list view with card but still same error

Comment: wrap the ListView with a Container and try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `shrinkWrap: true` to both your ListView widgets

```dart
isClicked? StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: db.where("Uid", isEqualTo: Uid.text).snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
              return ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  Text(doc.data()['name']),
                  Text(doc.data()['DateOfBirth']),
                  Text(doc.data()['crime']),
                  Text(doc.data()['criminalHistory']),
                ],
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  )
:Container()
    ]));
```